# Create a tag synonym for behavio(u)r

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

We have both the [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) and the [behaviour](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behaviour) tag. At the moment, American spelling is winning 6:2 but we should probably settle on the one and make the other a synonym.

I'm not sure who has the power to do this, but it seems I can't anyway.

Comment: Making tag synonyms is reserved for mods or higher rep users. Because we are a private beta, right now anyone with 1250 rep or above can do it, or since we don't have moderators as of yet, hopefully a Community Manager will see this and do it for you, because I think it makes a great deal of sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tag should be spelled [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior).  Tags are supposed to use the US English spelling, per [this meta.SO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23873/232449).

Comment: That is true! Now we just need someone to make the synonym and we will be good to go :)

Comment: Since there were only 2 questions tagged [behaviour], I've suggested edits to change them both to [behavior]. A synonym would still be a good idea, possibly.

Comment: Once somebody types "beh" he'll be offered [tag:behavior]; do we need "behaviour" as a synonym?  (I don't mind; I'm just asking.)

Comment: Synonyms should only be used when there are two different words with the same meaning. You would pick one ([behavior] is correct here) and retag. The text completion completion will take care of the rest. Down the road a bit, it will require higher reputation to create new tags so this type of problem passes quickly, but we don't create synonyms to cover all possibilities of pluralization, tense, and spelling variations.

Answer (score 1):

Manually re-tagging the posts has since removed the alternative spelling all together, now people will be presented with an auto-complete of the desired spelling.

I think the solution is to just manually maintain the single tag for now and hope people use the auto-complete functionality.